# Selecting UITableViewCell programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, ios4

I want to make a now playing button for my radio application. So would like to know how can I select a row programmatically I thought of calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath method but apparently we can't call it.

Comment: Could you please be specific ? You want a row to be selected - and you do not want to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath ???

Comment: Okay here is what I have thought...when ever the user hits the now playing button the row that was last selected will be selected back again taking back to the now playing view....makes scenes?

Answer (score 1):

[didSelectRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW14) is the method from delegate and it's called when you touch (select) the row in [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Use below method to selct a row on your `UITableView` instance.

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```

See Sample code.

```
[myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

Comment: tried that but that isn't working...it again reloads the view I mean the mp3 streamer I am using is re started...

Comment: @Tushar Chutani : if you try to reload the table again, you would loose the last selected row ..

Answer (score 0):

There is tableView method like [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:anIndexPathObject animated:BOOL-Flag]; .By calling this method you can select the row programmatically. But you also need to create an index path object.